# Solving Difference Equation Using Z-Transform

Tags: signal, signal-processing, signal-theory, z-transform

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I was trying to solve a problem given in my textbook. I have attached the solution given in the book.

I thought some modifications where needed to it and tried to solve in a different way. I ended up getting absurd results. Where's the mistake in my approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but the problem is that the given response is not the response to a *unit* step, but to a scaled step. That's why you get \$\alpha y[-1]=-11/2\$ and \$1-\alpha y[-1]=8\$, which is incompatible. If you assume a scaled step \$ku[n]\$, you end up with the following \$\mathcal{Z}\$-transform of the output signal:

$$Y(z)=\frac{k-\alpha y[-1]+\alpha y[-1]z^{-1}}{(1-z^{-1})(1+\alpha z^{-1})}\tag{1}$$

Comparing \$(1)\$ to the \$\mathcal{Z}\$-transform of the given response you get

$$k-\alpha y[-1]=8,\quad \alpha y[-1]=-\frac{11}{2},\quad\alpha=-\frac12$$

from which you obtain

$$y[-1]=11\quad\text{and}\quad k=\frac{5}{2}$$

The values of \$\alpha\$ and \$y[-1]\$ do not change, but now the result is compatible with the given response.

Comment: Thanks alot @MattL !! I tried everything but missed this subtle point.

Answer (score 0):

\$u(n)\$ is the unit step sequence, and is zero for negative \$n\$, hence \$y(-1)=0\$.

Comment: \$y[-1]\$ is the initial condition and is not represented by the given formula for \$y[n]\$, which is only valid for \$n\ge 0\$. If \$y[-1]\$ were zero, then the output would be different.

Comment: @MattL, can you suggest something ?